# Strange force closing

Tags: android

I have an app which works perfectly on my Galaxy Nexus, but when i run it on the emulator (only on some setups, one is tablet with JB and the other is ldpi with android 2.1) it crashes.

The logcat looks like this

```
03-29 16:26:16.842: D/AndroidRuntime(526): Shutting down VM
03-29 16:26:16.842: W/dalvikvm(526): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-29 16:26:16.842: E/AndroidRuntime(526): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.doublep.wakey/com.doublep.wakey.Bulb}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.doublep.wakey.Bulb.onCreate(Bulb.java:465)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-29 16:26:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  ... 11 more
03-29 16:26:16.882: I/dalvikvm(526): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-29 16:26:16.882: E/dalvikvm(526): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
03-29 16:26:18.752: I/Process(526): Sending signal. PID: 526 SIG: 9
```

I've discovered that if i comment out a button the problem goes away (this was an imageButton before, but i converted it to button, as imageButton it was working fine)

```
//This is a global variable declariation
    Button premiumFeaturesBtn; 


//this is inside the oncreate
    premiumFeaturesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_premium_features); 

//this is inside a thread
    premiumFeaturesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent premiumPurchase = new Intent(Bulb.this, PremiumPurchase.class);
                            startActivity(premiumPurchase);
                       }
                    });

//This is at the end of my onCreate
    Typeface bebas = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/bebas_neue.otf");
            premiumFeaturesBtn.setTypeface(bebas);
```

After commenting out the above lines everything works fine
This is the xml of the button

```
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_premium_features"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/img_btn_premium"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/premium_features"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Can you spot something i did wrong?
I think the problem is in this line

```
premiumFeaturesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_premium_features);
```

Because before i was getting sometimes the error saying that i can't cast Button on ImageButton
But obviously i am not

Comment: What happens when you get rid of the android:background attribute in your button definition?

Comment: Make sure you called `setContentView(R.layout.layoutName)` method before you are trying to initialise widgets via `findViewById()` method.

Comment: After removing the background it still crashes.
I am calling the setContentView at the beginnig of the onCreate, everything is done after it

Comment: @DoubleP90 Please post your complete code, to get the idea of what you are doing

Comment: are you sure you are getting a NPE?

Comment: @DoubleP90 You are initializing views in separate thread, which is not UI Thread, so your all views are Null, Why are you getting their reference in separate thread?

Comment: I'm doing this because if i do it in the main thread the startup of the app takes too long, and it works fine, just that single Button is giving me problems, so initializing the views in another thread is not what is causing the crashing.
The code causing the crash is on the line 264, if i comment that out (and everything relying on it) the app runs perfectly ok

Comment: Do you use different layouts for different screen sizes?

Comment: @Trinimon (*banging my head on the table*) yes i do....
I had the old ImageButton in the other layouts.
Post it as answer and i'll mark it.
I'm so ashamed of this error, i think i'm gonna hide in the closet

Comment: Don't mind. First I didn't dare to ask - but then I thought about some silly things I made ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different behavior on various devices can result in using different layouts being defined for screen sizes, orientations, and so on.

Check if the button identifier (`android:id="@+id/btn_premium_features"`) is defined in all of your applicable layouts.

This would explain why it runs on certain devices and doesn't on others.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is inside a thread
premiumFeaturesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

It shouldn't be inside any other than than main / UI thread where `onCreate` is executing.

Comment: If i comment it out or move it to the main thread it crashes aswell

Comment: @DoubleP90 Do what Pragnani suggested.